# The concept of $\epsilon - N$ proofs

Tags: calculus, limits

I just don't understand how to complete $\epsilon - N$ proofs. I don't know what my goal is or why they prove what they do. I have asked two questions on here in the past, but I simply don't 'get it'.

So first we set $\epsilon \gt 0$ and we want to find $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n \geq N$, we then take the $|a_n - a| \lt \epsilon$. We then reduce $|a_n - a|$ to simplest form and move everything apart from $n$ to the otherside of the equality. Where we let the floor of all this(Eq) equal $N$.

Back to $n \geq N = \lfloor{Eq}\rfloor$
${}$
Then we have $|a_n - a| \leq |a_{Eq} - a| \lt \epsilon$

With some ending statement, eg: "If $n \leq N = Eq$, then $|a_n - a| \lt \epsilon$, this meaning $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} a_n = a$

Is this what is meant to be done? Am I just trying to prove $|a_n - a| \lt \epsilon$ by subbing in a created $N$ in place of $n$, where created $N$ is some $k \epsilon$ where $k$ is just some divisor or multiple.

What is the simplest way to think of this problem?

Comment: It's simple: There's an enemy which gives you $\varepsilon>0$, you find $N\in\mathbb N$, the enemy gives you $n\ge N$ and you win if $|a_n-a|<\varepsilon$, else you lose. Find a winning strategy.

Comment: @user2345215 This is actually really helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you and your friend examine the sequence $a_n=3+1/n$. You look at $a_1, a_2, ...a_{100}$ and notice that $a_n$ approaches the value 3.

**So you tell your friend**: "I think that $a_n$ approaches the value 3."

**Friend**: "What do you mean?"

**You**: "Well, if $n$ gets larger, then $a_n$ gets closer to 3".

**Friend**: "So you're saying that $a_n$ gets arbitrarily close to 3? Hmm...ok. Show me that $a_n$ can have a distance of less than 0.25 from 3."

**You**: "Sure. If $n > 10$, then $|a_n -3| = |(3+1/n)-3|= 1/n < 1/10 < 0.25$.

**Friend:** "Why is $1/n < 1/10$?"

**You:** "That's because we chose $n>10$. So $1/n < 1/10$."

**Friend**: "Ok, but what about a distance of less than 0.004."

**You:** "Again, we can choose an even larger $n$, namely $n>1000$. Then the distance becomes
$|a_n -3| = |(3+1/n)-3|= 1/n < 1/1000 =0.001 < 0.004$."

**Friend:** "We have only checked that $a_n$ becomes close to 3 for these two examples. Can you show me that $a_n$ gets arbitrarily close to 3?"

**You:** "Yes. Suppose you give me a very small number $\epsilon > 0$, then I can always choose $n$ large enough, say $n>N$ for some fixed natural number $N$ such that $|a_n - 3| < \epsilon$. Here is how we can prove it:

You give me $\epsilon >0$. I choose $N>1/\epsilon$. If $n>N$ we have $|a_n -3| = |(3+1/n)-3|= 1/n < 1/N < \epsilon$."

**Friend**: "Very nice!"

Answer (score 0):

What is being considered is whether an infinite sequence of terms $(a_1, a_2, a_3, ...a_n, ..)$ converges to some value $a$. If it does, then you can say that in the limit as $n$ tends to infinity $a_n$ tends to $a$, or in mathematical notation, $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} a_n = a$.

So what does "convergence" mean ? It means that as you move further along in the sequence the terms get closer and closer to $a$.

How do you express mathematically that the terms are getting closer and closer to $a$ ? You consider by how much they differ from $a$, i.e. the value of $|a_n - a|$ and you would like to see this value getting smaller.

How do you express mathematically that you are moving further along the seqence ? You look at increasing values of $n$.

So to express that as you move further along in the sequence the terms get closer and closer to $a$, you say that given some value of $\epsilon >  0$ (which though it is not stated is assumed to be as small as we like) there exists $N$ (and again it isn't stated but it is assumed that $N$ can be as large as neccessary) such that for all $n > N$ we have  $|a_n - a| < \epsilon$.

To apply the concept directly to a sequence, you normally start from an equation giving the $n^{th}$ term and use it to calculate a value of $N$ that works for some given value of $\epsilon$. For example, take the sequence $(1, 1/2, 1/3, ....1/n,...)$, i.e. $a_n = 1/n$ which you would think converges to zero. To prove that it does, consider that given $\epsilon >0$ take  $N > 1/\epsilon$ and then for any $n>N$ we have $a_n< \epsilon$ which completes the proof.